# TrueCrypt: How can I mount an anonymous drive?

Tags: hard-drive, mount, truecrypt

(Windows 7, TrueCrypt v7.1a)

I use a batch file to mount two TrueCrypted disks when needed. On my old motherboard, the devices were initialized in constant order, and I could use

```
truecrypt.exe /volume \Device\HardDisk2\Partition1 [...]
truecrypt.exe /volume \Device\HardDisk3\Partition1 [...]
```

However, my new motherboard doesn't guarantee the order of initialization, and the above no longer works. I can use the volume name to mount one of the disks...

```
truecrypt.exe /volume \\?\Volume{501c1635-ff75-11e1-bbd4-806e6f6e6963}\ [...]
```

... but, for some reason, the other disk doesn't present a name. Here's the output of mountvol.exe with both drives dismounted :

```
\\?\Volume{501c1634-ff75-11e1-bbd4-806e6f6e6963}\
    C:\

\\?\Volume{f852e284-5831-4fac-8169-8396d76a9421}\
    E:\

\\?\Volume{501c1635-ff75-11e1-bbd4-806e6f6e6963}\
    *** NO MOUNT POINTS ***

\\?\Volume{a277745c-ff7a-11e1-b149-902b341e6b85}\
    D:\

\\?\Volume{501c1638-ff75-11e1-bbd4-806e6f6e6963}\
    F:\
```

C:, D:, and E: are all native NTFS partitions, F: is a DVD-RW. The '* * * NO MOUNT POINTS * * *' maps to *one* of the Truecrypt drives, and the other doesn't appear at all. However, after mounting both drives via the GUI, mountvol.exe now shows (in addition to the above)

```
\\?\Volume{d8b52edc-ff84-11e1-b794-902b341e6b85}\
    X:\

\\?\Volume{d8b52ee1-ff84-11e1-b794-902b341e6b85}\
    Y:\
```

Here's what diskpart.exe has to say for itself (both disks unmounted) :

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online           59 GB  1024 KB
  Disk 1    Online          465 GB  1024 KB        *
  Disk 2    Online         1863 GB      0 B
  Disk 3    Online         1397 GB      0 B

DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     F                       DVD-ROM         0 B  No Media
  Volume 1     C                NTFS   Partition     24 GB  Healthy    System
  Volume 2     D                NTFS   Partition     35 GB  Healthy
  Volume 3     E                NTFS   Partition    465 GB  Healthy
  Volume 4                      RAW    Partition   1397 GB  Healthy
```

Where Disk 3/Volume 4 is the device that does present a volume name, and Disk 2 the device that doesn't.

And the Windows Disk Management console, when asked about the (unmounted) mystery drive, says :

```
Volume = (null)
Layout = Simple
Type = Basic
File System = (null)
Status = Healthy (Primary Partition)
Capacity = 1863.01GB
Free Space = 1863.01GB
%Free = 100%
```

How can I refer to this drive when using truecrypt.exe to mount via a batch file?

**TL;DR : How can I mount a TrueCrypt disk via a batch file/command line, when I cannot use either the '\Device\HardDisk#\Partition#' or '\?\Volume{* - * - * - * - *}\' forms of identification? TrueCrypt's GUI's 'Select Device and Mount...' works fine, but I want to be able to mount this via a batch file. How? I seem to remember reading something about changing the partition type byte, but I'm understandably wary about that. Could someone talk me through it?**

Answer (score 1):

After shuffling around and backing up 2Tb of data, I managed to succeed.

You'll need a known good *Type ID*, either from somewhere like http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/partitions/partition_types-1.html , or from a working TrueCrypt partition. In order to be safe(r), I took the Type ID from my other, working, TrueCrypt drive like so :

Using DiskPart.exe

```
SELECT DISK [known good TrueCrypt drive #]
SELECT PARTITION [known good TrueCrypt partition #]
DETAIL PARTITION
```

Take note of the hex number in the 'Type' field. Mine was *06*.

Back into DiskPart to set the ID on the bad drive

```
SELECT DISK [bad TrueCrypt drive #]
SELECT PARTITION [bad TrueCrypt partition #]
SET ID=[known good Type ID] OVERRIDE
```

Wait for a few heart-stopping moments, as DiskPart decides whether or not to destroy years of work and data, and you should see

> DiskPart successfully set the partition ID

and MountVol.exe should now list the drive with the expected '* * * NO MOUNT POINTS * * *' message. Henceforth, you can now use the **\ \?\Volume{...}** name to access this TrueCrypt partition via the command line.

Note : As I mentioned, this was successful *for me*, but since I didn't know what I was doing, I make no guarantees.

Comment: Hi! To have your accounts merged, please visit this help site and follow the procedure there: http://superuser.com/help/user-merge (Hint: Using a non-throwaway e-mail address and registering the account helps in these cases of cookie loss)